# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main - code

Tags: java

Here is the source code for the program I wrote.

```
public class DVDInventoryProgram {
    final int MAX = 5;
    DVDsList dt[] = new DVDsList[MAX];
    int numberOfDVDs = 0;

    public void arraySort(int count) {
        int pass, i;
        int temp;
        DVDsList s = null;

        if (count > 1) {
            for (pass = 1; pass < count; pass++) {
                for (i = 0; i < count - pass; i++) {
                    temp = (dt[i].getName()).compareTo(dt[i + 1].getName());

                    if (temp > 0) {
                        s = dt[i];
                        dt[i] = dt[i + 1];
                        dt[i + 1] = s;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public float totalValueOfInventory() {
        float inventoryValue = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDVDs; i++) {
            inventoryValue = inventoryValue + dt[i].getInventoryValue();
        }

        return inventoryValue;
    }

    public void displayDVD(int index) {
        System.out.println("Name:                   " + dt[index].getName());
        System.out.println("ID:                     " + dt[index].getProductID());
        System.out.println("Unit Price:             " + dt[index].getUnitPrice());
        System.out.println("Units in Stock:         " + dt[index].getUnitsInStock());
        System.out.println("Total Product Value:    " + dt[index].getInventoryValue());
        System.out.println("Director:               " + dt[index].getDirector());
        System.out.println("Restocking Fee:         " + dt[index].getRestockFee());
        System.out.println("\nTotal Value of Inventory: " + totalValueOfInventory());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String name;
        int number;
        long stock;
        float price;
        String director;

        DVDinventoryProgram dip = new DVDinventoryProgram();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("<<<DVD Inventory Program>>>");
        System.out.println();

        DVDsList dvd;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter a DVD Title(or STOP to End Program): ");
            name = input.nextLine();

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.print("Enter a Product ID: ");
            number = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter the Unit Price: ");
            price = input.nextFloat();

            System.out.print("Enter the Number of Units in Stock: ");
            stock = input.nextLong();

            input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter the Name of the Director: ");
            director = input.nextLine();

            dvd = new DVDsList(name, number, price, stock, director);

            if (dip.numberOfDVDs < dip.MAX) {
                dip.dt[dip.numberOfDVDs] = dvd;
                dip.numberOfDVDs++;
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("<<< NEW DVD >>>");
                dip.displayDVD(dip.numberOfDVDs - 1);
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nArray is full. Please stop entering information.");
            }

        }

        dip.arraySort(dip.numberOfDVDs);

        System.out.println("\n<<< DVD LIST BY NAME >>>\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < dip.numberOfDVDs; i++) {
            dip.displayDVD(i);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("End of Program.");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us the line number where the error occured?

Comment: *Please* indent your code correctly; it's unreadable as it is...

Comment: How are you running this program?

Comment: Make sure you're doing "javac DVDInventoryProgram.java" to compile to byte-code and "java DVDInventoryProgram" to run the .class bytecode in the JVM. Note that the Java source-code name (.java file name) should be the same as for the class. I'll be surprised if this doesn't take care of your problem.

Comment: That exception shows up when you try to run a class that doesn't have a main method.  Are you sure you're running the right class from the right directory?  And when you run, e.g. "java DVDinventoryProgram" make sure you don't include the .class.

Answer (score 1):

To compile:

```
javac DVDInventoryProgram.java
```

and run:

```
java -classpath . DVDInventoryProgram
```